# ASP.NET MVC - prevent fallback to default route if mandatory parameter specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

I have the following route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "SetPassword",
        "Account/SetPassword/{token}",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "SetPassword" }
    );
```

and I want the token to be mandatory. But the problem is that if the token is missing, route falls back to the default one:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

What I want is to return `404 Not Found` if someone enters an address like
http://mysite.com/Account/SetPassword

How do I specify that the token is mandatory parameter and the routing must stop at this route if controller and action names match the specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do would be to put a Route Constraint on your Default Route, preventing it matching any actions in the Account Controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                        action = "Index", 
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "^(?!Account$).*" } }
);
```

Another thing that you could do would be to throw an HttpException in your action if Token was empty.

```
public ActionResult SetPassword(string token)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Page not found");
    }
    ViewBag.Token = token;
    return View();
}
```